# A well supported alternative to c++ unions?

Tags: c++, unions

I think that unions can be perfect for what i have in mind and especially when I consider that my code should run on a really heterogeneous family of machines, especially low-powered machine, what is bugging me is the fact that the people who creates compilers doesn't seem to care too much about introducing and offering a good union support, for example [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) is practical empty when it comes to *Unrestricted Unions* support, and this is a real unpleasant view for my projects.

There are alternatives to `union` that can at least mimic the same properties ?

Comment: @CodingMash a signal based system like the SDL one and storing types that can be "fractioned" like the classic RGB value example.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what you need?  Unions are a very old feature from C and are fully supported in all C++ compilers.  "Unrestricted Unions" are a change to unions and are new in C++11.  Read the included feature description linked from that table in your link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Union is well supported on most compilers, what's not well supported are unions that contains members that have non trivial constructor (unrestricted unions). In practice, you'd almost always want a custom constructor when creating unions, so not having unrestricted union is more of a matter of inconvenience.

Alternatively, you can always use void pointer pointing to a malloc-ed memory with sufficient size for the largest member. The drawback is you'd need explicit type casting.

Answer (score 6):

One popular alternative to union is [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant.html).

The types you use in it have to be copy-constructible.

**Update:**
C++17 introduced [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Its requirements are based on  Boost.Variant. It is modernized to take into account the features in C++17. It does not carry the overhead of being compatible with C++98 compilers (like Boost). It comes for free with standard library. If available it is better to use it as alternative to unions.

Comment: the word "template" doesn't sound really good in this case when i just need to zip types and make them really compact; it's also a pain developing and debugging templates. This abstraction level can cost me more than what it can give me.

Comment: If you want to avoid templates then you need to write all the casting involved and type checking by hand.

Comment: @user1849534 Did you look at how `boost:variant` is used? It's dark template magic on the inside, but you don't need to define templates yourself when using them (but you can, of course). See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic

Comment: @delnan I'm not allergic to templates, the "problem" is that the benefit of an union is the fact that it works in a really simple way, introducing templates, that are the hardest thing to debug + another library, doesn't look like a premium choice ...

Comment: @user1849534: The benefit of boost variant is that it is already well tested on number of compilers so you are perhaps overestimating the amount of testing and debugging that you need to do.

Comment: @user1849534 templates are incredibly powerful and useful and make it far easier to develop and maintain certain functionality than alternatives. If you're so worried about templates that you think a simple, single level template like the one ybungalobill showed will produce the incomprehensible errors you've seen elsewhere, then you just haven't used templates enough.

Comment: IME, fear of templates generally stems from using STL containers, which do have scary looking errors. But plain template errors are generally not that bad.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do essentially the same thing using explicit casts:

```
struct YourUnion {
    char x[the size of your largest object];
    A &field1() { return *(A*)&x[0]; }
    int &field2() { return *(int*)&x[0]; }
};

YourUnion y;
new(&y.field1()) A(); // construct A
y.field1().~A(); // destruct A
y.field2() = 1;
// ...
```

(This is zero overhead compared to, e.g., Boost.Variant.)

**EDIT:** more union-like and without templates.

Comment: You'll need to ensure that the storage is properly aligned.

Comment: @user1849534: you do not have to use templates... you can write the cast by hand each time.

Comment: @user1849534 Why would you want to avoid templates?

Comment: If supported, use `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: @ybungalobill well, it's a solution, but man i miss the plain old union approach ...

Comment: @user1849534 If you think simple templates like the one ybungalobill showed originally would be too hard to debug then you ought to be frightened of unrestricted unions too; unlike most of C++ you have to manually manage the members' lifetimes and if you get it wrong the compiler won't tell you, you'll just get undefined behavior.