# C++ equivalent of Union in C?

Tags: c++, c

Lately I have been studying C and I came across the concept of Union.
I like it because it can be used to represent any data type.
Of course it is helpful only for certain rare and special circumstances.
In C++ everything is done with classes.
Of course similar functionality like Union can be implemented using classes.
So I wanted to know whether C++ supports a Union equivalent, so that I don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Unions also exist in C++ as well.

Comment: C++ does have unions... less trolling bitte.

Comment: pretty much everything C has C++ also has.

Comment: But usually its a bad thing to use C functionality in C++, right? For example we use cout instead of printf.

Comment: Yeah but we still use variables (which is a C functionality) in C++ for example, don't we? ;)

Comment: I know plenty of people who continue to use printf in C++ (easier to format, IMO).

Comment: "But usually its a bad thing to use C functionality in C++, right?" - no... not "usually".  There are a few problematic or limited interfaces in C that are improved upon with the C++ Standard Library - given more reusability, efficiency, type safety, modularity etc - but C++ isn't a rejection of everything from C.

Comment: @Cool_Coder well that is a different question and similar to [A well supported alternative to c++ unions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553844/a-well-supported-alternative-to-c-unions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want `Boost.Variant`.

C++ does have `union` like in C, but because a `union` doesn't keep track of what type is stored in it, it wouldn't be able to execute the correct destructor if used with non-trivial types. The resulting restrictions on the use of `union` in C++ make it quite non-general.

Comment: ha, never thought of Boost.Variant as a sort of a union type, +1 for dem POVs!